# Partial trace and preserving positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace, positive-semidefinite

This question is related to topics in quantum information but I will present it as a linear algebra question here.

Consider some matrix $\delta_{AB}$ that lives in a bipartite Hilbert space $H_A\otimes H_B$. The partial trace map traces over one of the Hilbert space so we obtain the reduced matrices as below

$$\delta_A = \text{Tr}_B(\delta_{AB}), \, \, \delta_B = \text{Tr}_A(\delta_{AB})$$

Denote $A\geq B$ to mean that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. Let $\rho_{AB}$ and $\sigma_{AB}$ both be positive semidefinite matrices with trace $1$. Let $\lambda, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$ each be the smallest real numbers such that the following relationships hold

$$\rho_{AB} - \lambda\sigma_{AB} \geq 0$$ 
$$\rho_{A} - {\lambda_1}\sigma_{A} \geq 0$$ 
$$\rho_{B} - {\lambda_2}\sigma_{B} \geq 0$$

What is the relationship between $\lambda$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$? I'm looking for some kind of non-trivial inequality that relates all three.

---

By partial tracing over the conditions above, one sees that $\lambda\geq \lambda_1$ and similarly $\lambda\geq\lambda_2$ but I feel that more can be said.

Comment: Have you asked on Quantum Computing Stack Exchange? I'd be surprised if more than 0.1% of the people here know what a partial trace is, and you have also written "density matrix" instead of just "matrix" which is going to scare away the 0.1% remaining. Also, shouldn't your matrices be Hermitian? You forgot to tell that to the Mathematicians here. Have you considered asking on MathOverflow, where the audience is more advanced?

Comment: Another question: let's say rho and sigma are diagonalized already, and the diagonals/eigenvalues/probabilities for rho are [0.5 0.2 0.1] and for sigma are [0.3 0.4 0.1], then diag(rho - sigma) = [0.2 -0.2 0.0]. What value of lambda will make this $\ge$ 0 ?

Comment: if I'm not applying rules wrong since $tr(\delta_{AB})=tr(\delta_A tr_B(\delta_{AB}))$ I think it could be $1-\lambda =tr(\rho_{AB}-\lambda\sigma_{AB}) =tr((\rho_A-\lambda\sigma_A)tr_B(\rho_{AB}-\lambda\sigma_{AB})) =tr((\rho_A-\lambda\sigma_A)tr(\rho_B-\lambda\sigma_B)) =tr(\rho_B-\lambda\sigma_B)tr(\rho_A-\lambda\sigma_A)=(1-\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_1)
$

Comment: @DanielD. no, that's not correct. $tr(\delta_{AB}) = tr(tr_B(\delta_{AB}))$ but you have an extra $\delta_A$ in your expression

Comment: @user1271772 in your example, if the matrices were simultaneously diagonalizable, then one sees that $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. For this value, $\rho - \lambda\sigma = diag(0.35, 0, 0.05)$ and any smaller $\lambda$ would violate positive semidefiniteness of $\rho - \lambda\sigma$. You have to look at $\rho - \lambda\sigma$ not $\rho - \sigma$

Comment: thanks! so it should be $tr(\delta_{AB})=tr(tr_B(\delta_{AB}))=tr(\delta_Atr(\delta_B))$ and then $1-\lambda =tr(\rho_{AB}-\lambda\sigma_{AB})=tr(tr_B(\rho_{AB}-\lambda\sigma_{AB}))=tr((\rho_A-\lambda\sigma_A)tr(\rho_B-\lambda\sigma_B)) =tr(\rho_B-\lambda\sigma_B)tr(\rho_A-\lambda\sigma_A)=(1-\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_1)$

Comment: Daniel's comment leads to $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - \lambda_2\lambda_1$ which means that $\lambda \ge \lambda_{1,2}$ is not necessarily true if they are >1. But maybe they will always be less than 1 (in the example I gave, you said that we have a value of 1/2.